# String manipulation code gives no output

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, mips

So basically, i have to flip the string in place without knowing is size.
so i wrote code to find the size and then substitute characters in the string from both sides till we reach the middle and we are done. However, my code gives no output and my brain is boiling right now
can someone please help

```
    # a program to reverse a string in memory (without allocating additional memory)
.data
string: .asciiz "CMPS 255"

.text

#find the length of the string
li $s0, 0 #max index
li $s1, 0 #initial index

findNull:lb $t0,string($s0)
    beq $t0,$zero,foundNull
    add $s0,$s0,1
    j findNull

foundNull:

    beq $s0, $s1, done
    lb $t1, string($s0) #right value
    lb $t2, string($s1) #left value
    sb $t1, string($s1) #switched
    sb $t2, string($s0) #switched
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    subi $s0, $s0, 1
    j foundNull

done:

la $a0,string
li $v0, 4

syscall
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: i am using mar for coding and it runs normally just no output

Comment: i meant to say im using mars so yeah i have a debugger

Comment: So what are the contents of `string` when you reach the `syscall` instruction?

Comment: i should get the string in reverse what im doing is just saving chars from the string address in temp registers and swapping them from the left most side to the right most side till i reach the middle and terminate

Comment: When your code doesn't do what you expect, single-step through it in a debugger *before* posting it on SO.  If you're still stuck, then you can describe how it executes and how that's different from what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

So, i took a moment and wrote some pseudo code for this algorithm...
i followed the exact steps as last time but this time my work was more organized and here is my final ans. i hope it is helpful for who ever finds it

```
 .data
string: .asciiz "hello"

.text
la $a1, string
li $t9,0 #counter for the size

loop:
lb $a2, ($a1)
beq $a2, $zero, found
addi $a1, $a1, 1
add $t9, $t9, 1
j loop

found: #its time to reverse
sub $t9, $t9, 1 #max index
li $t8 , 0 #staring index

looptwo:
beq $t8, $t9, done
lb $t1, string($t8) #left most
lb $t2, string($t9)#right most
sb $t1, string($t9)
sb $t2, string($t8)
add $t8, $t8 , 1
sub $t9, $t9 , 1
j looptwo

done:
li $v0 , 4
la $a0, string
syscall
```